# How do I free up the memory consumed by a string literal?

Tags: c, memory-management, string-literals

How do I free up all the memory used by a `char*` after it's no longer useful?

I have some `struct`

```
struct information
{
/* code */
char * fileName;
}
```

I'm obviously going to save a file name in that `char*`, but after using it  some time afterwards, I want to free up the memory it used to take, how do I do this?

E: I didn't mean to free the pointer, but the space pointed by `fileName`, which will most likely be a string literal.

Comment: You should `free` what you `malloc` (or `calloc`/`realloc` etc.), but other than that there's nothing to do.

Comment: The sapce of `fileName` is freed when you free its containing struct. Or do you want to free the space `fileName` **points to**?

Comment: That last one, olaf, say I do fileName = "some literal";, I want to free the "some literal".

Comment: Don't try to do that.  It will end up in tears, and segfaults.

Comment: *I want to free the "some literal"* It's not yours to free. A literal is an object having lifetime managed by the compiler/language runtime.

Comment: It's strange but it's true, you do not need to, and cannot, free up string literals.

Comment: Just a side question then, when are the string literals freed? As soon as your program execution ends?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD yes, usually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are multiple string "types" `fileName` may point to:

1. Space returned by `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc`. In this case, use `free`.
2. A string literal. If you assign `info.fileName = "some string"`, there is no way. The string literal is written in the executable itsself and is usually stored together with the program's code. There is a reason a string literal should be accessed by `const char*` only and C++ only allows `const char*`s to point to them.
3. A string on the stack like `char str[] = "some string";`. Use curly braces to confine its scope and lifetime like that:

   ```
   struct information info;
   {
       char str[] = "some string";
       info.fileName = str;
   }
   printf("%s\n", info.fileName);
   ```

   The `printf` call results in undefined behavior since `str` has already gone out of scope, so the string has already been deallocated.

Comment: Long answer short: only `free` previously `malloc`ed (and family) objects.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `foo.fileName = malloc(howmanychars);` and `free(foo.fileName);`.

You cannot free the memory if you initialize `fileName` from a string literal or other non-dynamically allocated way.

But then, freeing a handful of bytes is next to pointless, unless you need a large number of such structs/fileNames. The OS will likely **not** return the freed memory to other processes; the returned memory *may* be available for future memory allocations of your process.